# How do I convert files .mdf & .ldf to mysql format

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not familiar with these files `.MDF & .LDF`. I want to convert both to MySQL format or `.CSV`.

Let me know how can be done. Any tools or scripts can convert it.

Comment: Look at the files in notepad and they might already be in a format you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both SQL Server files.  MDF is a database file, and LDF is a transaction log file.

The way to extract data from them is by attaching them to an instance of SQL Server.  If the database file is smaller than 5GB, you can attach it to the [free edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/).  If not, you'll need a real version of SQL Server.

The version of SQL Server has to match the version that you got the MDF file from.  Sometimes, a newer server version can read an older MDF, but don't count on it.

Once you've got the database attached, you can generate a CSV file in many ways.  One easy way is to "Save Results As" from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks Andomar. Let me download the free edition first. Hope same version with current MDF file. Million thanks for the information.

Comment: Hmmm.. current MDF file from MSSQL 2000. So I need SQL v. 2000 to convert it?

Comment: @normala: Yes-- 2005 might work, but 2000 is best.  [The free version of 2000 was called MSDE.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413744d1-a0bc-479f-bafa-e4b278eb9147)

Answer (score 2):

You don't

You have to [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) them to a SQL Server Instance and then use of of the [Wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx). or import from a MySQL instance-